# Clojure map limits and consistency

Tags: hash, dictionary, clojure, hashmap

I would like to know , considering that Clojure uses 32-bit hash for its map implementation, if Clojure map has therefore a limit of 2^32-1 keys (and if this is not true, how it manages collisions) and if its hashing implementation is [consistent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consistent_hashing).
TIA!

Comment: Have you looked at the source code?

Comment: Yep, but I cannot fully understand it because I'm not a Java developer: from what I've understood the hash function is hasheq which delegates to Integer in the particular case that key is an Integer and to key Object hasheq method. But I cannot understand (or back trace) the hash function used, if the map support collisions and if the hash function is consistent!

Comment: (I'll never understand some downvotes)

Comment: Sorry, I meant the source for PersistentHashMap, which is in Java. @mikera has already linked to it in his answer and explained how it works, so I don't think I'll have much to add.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Clojure maps are a custom implementation that is **persistent and immutable** (i.e. it does *not* use Java hashmaps, which would not provide sufficient performance when used in an immutable data structure).

It uses 32-bit hash codes, hence **2^32 possible hash buckets**. In the case of collisions, keys and values are stored in an array for each hash bucket so it is **possible to have more than 2^32 keys**. See the [PersistentHashMap source](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/PersistentHashMap.java) - in particular the HashCollisionNode inner class is used to store a bucket of keys / values against a single hashcode value.

Since the number of possible hash buckets is fixed, consistent hashing is irrelevant - the key never need to be remapped.

See also:

- http://www.infoq.com/presentations/Value-Identity-State-Rich-Hickey (presentation explaining Clojure approach to concurrency but also covers the persistent immutable data structures)