# Clojure associative data type with heterogeneous key/value hash strategy?

Tags: clojure

How does having any data type as a key (in maps) work.

For example:

```
(defn foo [a] (identity a))

(def  dict {1 "One", foo "foo", true "True", "etc." "Ecetera", [1 2 3] "Really?"})
```

Which strategy is used so that they keys don't collide?

**EDIT**

The link in Leon's comment has more value than the referenced SO question. However; I will accept that this has been answered.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Clojure map limits and consistency](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11082916/clojure-map-limits-and-consistency)

Comment: @LeonGrapenthin that may answer it. Do I understand it that the 2^32 are *potential* buckets? Are the keys hashes simply the object hash of the type (e.g. String.hash, Integer,hash, Bool.hash) and the inner collision class handles same key hash different key values?

Comment: http://clojure.org/reference/data_structures#Collections

Comment: Keys *do* collide. Since clojure maps are immutable and persistent, it's a fair bet that they are based on the same balanced trees of object pointers that sustain vectors. There are many strategies for resolving collisions, which apply to vectors of objects, however implemented.